# iPhone 5 picking up tablet media query

Tags: iphone, html, css

For some reason, my iPhone is picking up styles within the followind media query:

`@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 900px)`

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone5 Screen is larger than 900px(It's 1136)

Took this from another Question:

Pre iPhone 5:
'@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}'

iPhone 5:
'@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}'

iPad:
'@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}'